# Array to String Conversion Error / PDO execute array in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

So i'm having an issue executing a query using PDO execute. The error I keep getting back from the server is that I have an array to string conversion. It then follows up by telling me that there is also an invalid number of parameters entered into the `execute(array())` line of code. I also get a `1` buffer in my error code, which means there may be some bad concatenation.

The function is a search page where the user inputs up to 6 parameters to search for a book by. There are 6 if statements to check for emptys and if not empty then the variable is added to the array `params` and part of an sql query concatenated to the end of the beginning statement. Here is the pertinent code:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$publisher = $_POST['publisher'];
$isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
$condition = $_POST['condition'];
$status = $_POST['status'];

//array to hold variables
$params = array();
$concat_stmt_orig = "SELECT * FROM Book WHERE ";
$concat_stmt = "SELECT * FROM Book WHERE ";

//Check for Title
if(!empty($title)){
    //add title to the end
    $concat_stmt = $concat_stmt." `Title` = ?";
    //add variable to print list
    array_push($params, $title);

}
//Check for Author
if(!empty($author)){
    if(strlen($concat_stmt) !== strlen($concat_stmt_orig)){
        //add author to the end
        $concat_stmt = $concat_stmt." AND `Author1` = ?";
        //add variable to print list
        array_push($params, $author);
    }
    else{
        //add author to the end
        $concat_stmt = $concat_stmt." `Author1` = ?";
        //add variable to print list
        array_push($params, $author);
    }
}

//Check for publisher
if(!empty($publisher)){
    if(strlen($concat_stmt) !== strlen($concat_stmt_orig)){
        //add publisher to the end
        $concat_stmt = $concat_stmt." AND `Publisher` = ?";
        //add variable to print list
        array_push($params, $publisher);
    }
    else{
        //add pubisher to the end
        $concat_stmt = $concat_stmt." `Publisher` = ?";
        //add publisher to print list
        array_push($params, $publisher);
    }
}
//check for ISBN
if(!empty($isbn)){
    if(strlen($concat_stmt) !== strlen($concat_stmt_orig)){
        //add isbn to the end
        $concat_stmt = $concat_stmt." AND `ISBN` = ?";
        //add variable to print list
        array_push($params, $isbn);
    }
    else{
        //add pubisher to the end
        $concat_stmt = $concat_stmt." `ISBN` = ?";
        //add publisher to print list
        array_push($params, $isbn);
    }
}
//check for condition
if(!empty($condition)){
    if(strlen($concat_stmt) !== strlen($concat_stmt_orig)){
        //add condition to the end
        $concat_stmt = $concat_stmt." AND `BookCondition` = ?";
        //add condition to print list
        array_push($params, $condition);
    }
    else{
        //add condition to the end
        $concat_stmt = $concat_stmt." `BookCondition` = ?";
        //add condition to print list
        array_push($params, $condition);
    }
}

//check for status
if(!empty($status)){
    if(strlen($concat_stmt) !== strlen($concat_stmt_orig)){
        //add status to the end
        $concat_stmt = $concat_stmt." AND `Status` = ?";
        //add variable to print list
        array_push($params, $status);
    }
    else{
        //add condition to the end
        $concat_stmt = $concat_stmt." `Status` = ?";
        //add condition to print list
        array_push($params, $status);
    }
}

 //prepare statement for querying
 $stmt_retrieve = $db->prepare($concat_stmt);

 echo print_r($stmt_retrieve);
 var_dump($params);

 //exectue query
 $stmt_retrieve->execute(array($params));
}
```

echo and var dump were for testing purposes to check for the sql statement and the correct number of array values

Here are the errors

> PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM Book WHERE `Title` = ? AND `Author1` = ? ) 1array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "Example Title" [1]=> string(14) "Example Author" } 
>   Notice: Array to string conversion in...."yadayadayada"
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'...."yadayadayada"

I tried entering the post values as '$title', '$author'...etc but that still produced the errors, I've also tried printf and others.

I only get these errors when I try to input more than one variable to search by. When I only search by one variable the program has no errors but still won't return anything.

Any help or guidance is appreciated :)

Comment: This would probably be a bit easier to follow using an associative array and named placeholders. Also, try and compile your conditions in an array then join with `"AND"` as a last step. Having double branches the whole way down is massive duplication of effort and asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @tadman , will be sure to do it that way in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$stmt_retrieve->execute($params);`

Currently, you have the equivalent of:

```
$stmt_retrieve->execute(array(array('title','author1',....)));
```

See the double `array`  there?

@tadman is right that your current code has a *massive* code duplication which quickly becomes unmaintainable.

Something like this would help:

```
$fields = array(
   'Title'   => $_POST['title'],
   'Author1' => $_POST['author'],
   ....);

$params = array();
$wheres = array();

foreach($fields as $fieldname => $value){
    if(!empty($value)){
        $wheres[] = "`$fieldname` = ?";
        $params[] = $value;
    }
}
$stmt = 'SELECT * FROM Book';
if(!empty($wheres)) $stmt .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ',$wheres);
$stmt_retrieve = $db->prepare($stmt);
$stmt_retrieve->execute($params);
```

Comment: Good catch, fixed that issue with the array in an array and it worked. I agree, my method is extremely sloppy. Thanks for putting up a better way to do it, I didn't know that the implode() and explode() methods existed. Gotta go through the documentation more. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice fix there with the implode`.